# Работа с буфером вывода во время выполнения callback-функции ob_start()

Tags: php, view, шаблонизаторы

Мне нужно достать результат вывода подключенного php файла или любой другой функции в буфер браузера во время того, как редактируется вывод буфера в браузер

```
ob_start("onBufferFlush");

function onBufferFlush ($buffer) {
    ob_start();
    include("template.php");
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    return $content . $buffer;
}
```

"Я встроил тебе ob-функцию внутрь ob-функции, чтобы ты мог редактировать буфер пока редактируешь буфер"

Внутри такого callback'а функции семейства ob уже не вызываются. И вообще если внутри этого callback'а вызвать хотя бы 1 echo - на экран браузера не выведется ничего, ни буфера, ни ошибки, ни варнинга, просто белый лист.
Генерировать динамично html'ку налету в строковую переменную не хочу. Есть какие-нибудь варианты решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, так не получится, дело в том, что функция обратного вызова срабатывает в момент, когда буфер уже закрыт с одной стороны, и он не срабатывает на `ob_get_clean()` с другой.

Я бы предложил другой вариант: создать два последовательных буфера. При помощи первого вы создаете переменную `$template`, в которой сохраняете шаблон. Второй буфер формируется по вашей схеме - с использованием функции обратного вызова (в примере ниже она оформлена как анонимная). Так как такая функция может принимать только один аргумент, эту переменную можно передать через замыкание `use`. В момент вызова функции `ob_end_flush()`, сработает анонимная функция, которая передается `ob_start()`, где вы и задействуете `$template`.

```
<?php
ob_start();

include("template.php");
$template = ob_get_clean();

ob_start(function($buffer) use ($template) {
  return $template . $buffer;
});

echo "Основное содержимое";

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Опечатался, да, спасибо.
Дело в том, что хочу сосредоточить всю логику одного компонента в одном месте, а не разбивать ее на две части: до выполнения другого компонента и после. А так же хочу, чтобы преобразование буфера с использованием стороннего шаблона выполнялось и при умирании скрипта, например с помощью die()

Comment: Может быть вы подскажете как тогда вывести отложенную вьюху? Например, есть сайдбар, который инициализируется в хедере, а контент в него набирается по ходу страницы. Как шаблонизировать вьюху, если не php-файлом, в котором лежит разметка и небольшие вставки php-кода для динамики? Не собирать же строку, в самом деле? Либо я что-то делаю не так, либо уже давно есть этому решение. Может быть используют какие-то сторонние шаблонизаторы типа smarty?